# Multiple svn logjns for one VCS root in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity

Is there a way to configure user settings that he will have two svn logins for one user account?

I find out how to do this for separated VCS roots but in my comapny users have two svn logins.

Comment: Not that I know of. TeamCity maps 1 root to 1 login. You could always give TC it's own login and avoid the per-user issues.